# CentOS-8 - Unsealing LUKS volume with TPM2 module - clevis issue

Tags: centos, luks, dracut, tpm

Im trying to get a LUKS volume unlocked by the TPM-module on a Dell Optiplex 3060. The binding seems to work fine:

```
clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{"pcr_ids":"7"}'
```

```
$ luksmeta show -d /dev/nvme0n1p3
0   active empty
1   active cb6e8904-81ff-40da-a84a-07ab9ab5715e
2 inactive empty
(...)
```

I got this to work with an Oracle Linux 7.6 instance on the same machine, but with CentOS-8 the systems stops during boot at `Reached target Basic System`.
I figured out, that it's related with **clevis-dracut** respectively with the clevis kernel module. When I deactivate the module with `dracut -fv --regenerate-all -o "clevis"` (via Rescure-boot) the system boots again, but, of course, the encrypted volume gets not unlocked.
I can't get anything useful for me out of `journalctl`, that's why I'm stuck at this point.

So my questions are how I can get the system to boot with the clevis module enabled respectively how I can find the information I need to solve the stop while booting.